# use ffmpeg to overlay a video on top of another using an alpha channel

Tags: ffmpeg, alpha

Similar to what alphamerge / alphaextract do, but instead of having two sources I want to use three

InputVideo1, AlphaofInputVideo1, BackgroundVideo

The idea would be to overlay inputvideo1 on top of backgroundvideo using AlphaofInputVideo1 to do a more accuracte blending. Is this possible? Using intermediate steps (e.g. using alphamerge and generate intermediate rgba bitmaps) is acceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic syntax for this operation is

```
ffmpeg -i input -i alpha -i bg -filter_complex "[0][1]alphamerge[ia];[2][ia]overlay" out.mp4
```

The frame sizes of input and alpha must be the same. So should the framerate and framecount to avoid misaligned merges.

Comment: Exactly what I wanted

Comment: Out of curiosity. The way it works is that ia is a variable that holds the result of alphamerge 0 and 1, and then uses the overlay filter on that intermediate result and 2? Does that syntax work with other filters? It would allow me to do complex setups in a single command

Comment: Yes, your inference is right. It's called -filter_*complex* for a reason :)

Comment: I notice that when I use this command the framerate seems to be sped up 3x. Is this normal?

Comment: No; share full log.